# What can’t perl locate an object method via an installed module?

Tags: perl, module

I am running a Perl program that uses Math::Vector,
but I am getting the following error.

```
Can't locate object method "UnitVecPoints" via package "Math::Vector"
at /usr/local/share/perl5/Math/Vector.pm line 135.
```

How do I proceed? The module is correctly installed.

Comment: Can you show some code that triggers this error?

Answer (score 3):

The module is no longer on CPAN. I found it on backpan, though: http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/W/WS/WSYVINSKI/Vector.pm

It seems to call `UnitVecPoints`, but it only defines `UnitVectorPoints`. Try to edit the file `/usr/local/share/perl5/Math/Vector.pm`, providing the correct subroutine name.